# Dynamically loading classes which adhere to an interface

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I have several classes which implement two interfaces. All of them implement the *BaseInterface* and some other interface which is specific to them.

I want to be able to use the *loadClass* method below to instantiate classes which are referred to in a *.properties* file and call the common method they all contain (because they implement *BaseInterface*).

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    public void doBase();
}

public interface SpecificInterface extends BaseInterface {
    public void doSpecific();
}

public class SpecificClass implements SpecificInterface {
    public void doBase() { ... }

    public void doSpecific() { ... }
}

public class LoadClass() {
    private PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader = new PropertiesLoader();

    public <C extends BaseInterface> C loadClass(String propertyName) {
        Class<C> theClass;

        // Load the class.
        theClass = propertiesLoader.getPropertyAsClass(propertyName);

        // Create an instance of the class.
        C theInstance = theClass.newInstance();

        // Call the common method.
        theInstance.doBase();

        return theInstance;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code:

```
loadClassInstance.loadClass("SpecificClass");
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
SpecificClass cannot be cast to BaseInterface
at LoadClass.loadClass
```

Any ideas how I would solve this issue?

Many Thanks, Danny

Comment: You should take a look at the Java SPI libraries and how to use `META-INF/services`. It pretty much does all the stuff you're trying to do, and it's pretty simple to use. I'll post an example class momentarily.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java's Service Provider Interface (SPI) libraries allow you to load classes with public parameterless constructors dynamically based on the interfaces they implement, and it's all done through the use of `META-INF/services`.

First, you'll need the `interface`:

```
package com.example;

public interface SomeService {

    String getServiceId();

    String getDisplayName();
}
```

Then when you need them, you can load them using Java's [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class, which implements `Iterable`:

```
ServiceLoader<SomeService> loader = ServiceLoader.load(SomeService.class);
for (SomeService serv : loader) {
    System.out.println(serv.getDisplayName());
}
```

Then when you have 1 or more implementing classes on your classpath, they register themselves in `META-INF/services`. So if you have the implementation:

```
package com.acme;

public class SomeImplementation implements SomeService {

    // ...

    public SomeImplementation() { ... }

    // ...
}
```

Note that this class *needs* a default no-args constructor, this is not optional.

You register it with the class loader by creating a file in `META-INF/services` in your classpath (such as in the root of your jar) with the following properties:

1. The name of the file is the fully qualified class name of the interface, in this case, it's `com.example.SomeService`
2. The file contains a newline-separated list of implementations, so for the example implementation, it would contain one line: `com.acme.SomeImplementation`.

And there you go, that's it. How you build your project will determine where you put the `META-INF/services` stuff. Maven, Ant, etc. all have ways of handling this. I recommend asking another question about your specific build process if you have any trouble adding these files to your build.

Comment: That's fantastic - thanks very much!

Thank you to the other answerers also for their useful tips :).

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your code with below it works. I doubt that `PropertiesLoader` is doing something that is not supposed to be done.

```
    Class<?> theClass;
    // Load the class.
    theClass = Class.forName("SpecificClass");
    // Create an instance of the class.
    C theInstance = (C) theClass.newInstance();


   BaseInterface base =  loadClass();//There is no problem in casting
```

Answer (score 0):

Java program normally is loaded by system classloader. The classes which are referred to in a .properties file are loaded by a user-defined classloader. Classes loaded by different classloaders are considered different even if have same name and are loaded from same classfile. In your case, the interface BaseInterface loaded by system classloader is different from the BaseInterface loaded by 
PropertiesLoader.
To fix this, PropertiesLoader should delegate loading of BaseInterface to system classloader. Typical way to do so is to use system classloader as a parent classloader for PropertiesLoader.